# Qfuture consists of null pointer

Tags: qt, qtconcurrent

My Qt multi-threaded program crashes when it reaches :

```
      if(QFutureVar.isRunning())
```

I tried try-catch block, but that didn't work.

How can I check if it's null?

When I step-into my code in that line, debugger tells me:

```
       Signal name: SIGSEGV
       Signal meaning: Segmentation fault "
```

Comment: if `QFutureVar` is of type `QFuture` the call should work so i guess it might happen somewhere else. can you try to not run the code concurrent for debugging?

Comment: thank you, yes its a QFututre and I'm debugging my code, but when I step-over that line I get that error.